# PHP Login application - Check if username already exists when creating a new user

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, system

The title tells pretty much everthing, that needs to be said. I'm having a registration code looking like this:

I wan't it to check, if the username entered already exists, if it does - write and $errMsg = ""; and echo it out later.. I hope you can help me, thanks.

```
if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password']) && isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['last_name']) && isset($_POST['company'])){

            if($username === '') {
                $errMsg = "Du skal udfylde brugernavn";
            }
            elseif($password === ''){
                $errMsg = "Du skal udfylde password";
            }
            elseif($name === ''){
                $errMsg = "Du skal udfylde navn";
            }
            elseif($last_name === ''){
                $errMsg = "Du skal udfylde efternavn";
            }
            elseif($company === ''){
                $errMsg = "Du skal udfylde firma";
            }
                $sql = ("SELECT * FROM members WHERE username ='$username'");
                $result = mysql_query($sql) or die('error');
                $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
                    if(mysql_num_rows($result)) {
                            $errMsg = 'Brugernavn findes, vælg et andet.';
                } else {
                $sql = ("INSERT INTO members (username, password, name, last_name, company, salt)VALUES('$username', '$password', '$name', '$last_name', '$company', '$salt')")or die(mysql_error());

                if(mysql_query($sql))
                echo "Du er oprettet som profil.";
                }

            }//End whole if
```

Comment: Sidenote: There's some major sql injection possibility with this code.

Comment: @Dogbert Tell me? I'm using mysql_real_escape string, and trim and stuff like that htmlentities. Just not in the code here.

Comment: Your `validate()` function is terrible! Do not do that! You are doing both specialchars and entities? Whatever for? You will get double escapes. Why are you stripping slashes? What use could you have for that? Why would you store a HTML escaped version of the username? Store the real username, not an HTML version. You are doing `nl2br` AFTER the mysql escape? Use `htmlspecialchars()` on your OUTPUT not the input! For the input use `trim()` and `mysql_real_escape_string()` and nothing else. For the output use `htmlspecialchars()` OR `htmlentities()` and `nl2br()` if you need it.

Comment: I think the docs for `mysql_real_escape string` should have a big bold section that suggests the use of [prepared statements](http://mattbango.com/notebook/web-development/prepared-statements-in-php-and-mysqli/)!

Comment: @Ariel I see what you mean, haven't thought of that. Thanks :o)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Don't use `and` in your `if()` use `&&`
2. `empty()` already checks if the value is set. Instead do `$_POST['username'] === ''` note the three equals. Even better is to trim the result: `trim($_POST['username']) === ''`
3. You have an absolutely MASSIVE hole in your SQL that will get you completely hacked. YOU MUST USE `mysql_real_escape_string()`!!!! Like this:

   ```
    $sql = "INSERT INTO members (username, password, name, last_name, company, salt)VALUES('" . mysql_real_escape_string($username) . "', '" . mysql_real_escape_string($password) . "', '" . mysql_real_escape_string($name) . "', '" . mysql_real_escape_string($last_name) . "', '" . mysql_real_escape_string($company) . "', '$salt')";
   ```
4. To check if the record exists first try a `SELECT`:

   ```
   $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) num FROM members WHERE username = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($username) . "'";
   $result = mysql_query($sql) or die('error');
   $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
   if($row['num']) {
     $errMsg = 'Username exists';
   }
   ```

Alternative:

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE username = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($username) . "'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die('error');
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    if(mysql_num_rows($result)) {
      $errMsg = 'Username exists';
    }
```

The second version gives you the row if you need it, not just a count.

Comment: @Ariel As I commented above. I already DO use this.. I will edit my question with the full code if you like.. I just didn't post it here, for the length of the code.

Comment: That is good. In any case, I have posted the solution for you: Use a SELECT first and check it.

Comment: @Ariel Please look at the update of my question. And see ;o) + I will try the SELECT you posted :)

Comment: @Ariel What do you mean by #2 in your answer? I do not have to use if(isset(....) ?

Comment: @Ariel When I'm using $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) num FROM members WHERE username = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($username) . "'";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die('error');
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); 
if($row['num']) {
  $errMsg = 'Username exists';
} - it says that the username exists, but it creates the user anyway.

Comment: Well pick, either use `isset()` or use `empty()`. You don't need both. empty already checks if the value is set. Personally I would use the `isset()` at the top, then later just check if it is blank with `=== ''`. Remember ALWAYS use 3 equals when comparing to the empty string! `0 == ''` is `true` unfortunately, which can lead to some very strange errors.

Comment: You need to put the INSERT part in an `else` of that `if()`.

Comment: @Ariel I'm using the ISSET. And now I got it to stop inserting if the username exists. Now, when I use the: $username === ''; where should I write the $errMsg = ""; for this then?

Comment: Just change `empty($username)` to `$username === ''` otherwise leave the if structure as it is. (I'm assuming the $username is already trimmed.)

Comment: @Ariel Please look at my question now. This is how it looks. If something is empty it still sends. I can't put it into some else cus there's an else later on

Comment: After `firma"; }` add: `else {` and add another `}` at the bottom. Also instead of `echo "Du`... assign it to $errMsg and then you don't need to handle that special. Of course change the name from $errMsg to just $msg.

Answer (score 0):

```
//If anything is empty write an error.
if(empty($_POST['username'])){
$errMsg = "Du skal udfylde brugernavn.";
}
elseif(empty($_POST['password'])){
$errMsg = "Du skal udfylde password.";
}
elseif(empty($_POST['name'])){
$errMsg = "Du skal udfylde navn.";
}
elseif(empty($_POST['last_name'])){
$errMsg = "Du skal udfylde efternavn.";
}
elseif(empty($_POST['company'])){
$errMsg = "Du skal udfylde firma.";
} else {
$sql = (" SELECT * FROM users WHERE username ='.$username.'")
$res = mysql_query($sql) ;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res) ){
  $errMsg = "Your error message";
  exit();
}

$sql = ("INSERT INTO members (username, password, name, last_name, company, salt)VALUES('$username', '$password', '$name', '$last_name', '$company', '$salt')")or die(mysql_error());
if(mysql_query($sql))
echo "Du er oprettet som profil.";
}//End if empty else
```

I also took out the surrounding `if` - if it were to execute the `then`, then no error would of been displayed, because everything was set

Answer (score 0):

You will have to look it up.

```
 $sSelect = "SELECT FROM members WHERE username = ".$sUserName." LIMIT 1";
 $rResult = mysql_query($sSelect);
 if (mysql_num_rows($rResult) > 0) {
     echo 'error, it exists!';
 }
```

Comment: You mean `SELECT FROM` not `INSERT INTO`. As a side note why do you repeat the first letter of each variable name?

Comment: It's a coding standard I follow - it tells the type of the variable. so `$sString` or `$iInteger`, `$fFloat`, `$oObject`.

Comment: Ah. That's called Hungarian notation. I never found it to be at all useful, but some people like it.